# Sql Query condition based on column can holded bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is:

```
select
    ProdID, Qualified 
from 
    VarAnn_Data.dbo.tblOwnership
```

procedures output:

```
ProdID(num) Qual (Bit)
26  0
26  0
26  1
26  0
26  1
26  0
26  0
27  0
28  0
28  0
28  0
28  0
28  0
28  1
28  1
29  0
29  0
29  1
29  0
29  1
29  0
29  0
```

Now there are more than one and zero for single `prodid`. I got result with distinct

CASE 1:

```
ProdId(num)      Quak(bit)
26                  0
26                  1
```

result: A

```
ProdId(num)      Quak(bit)
26                  0
```

Result : B

```
ProdId(num)      Quak(bit)
26                  1
```

result : C

Comment: What is your question ? Show your data in table form.I'll be easier to determine

Comment: how did the results come up?

Comment: Thanks the question is there are three conditions i have some prodid contain only 1 row and some contains two. but in the case of one qual main be 1 or 0. so i need a query to identify its is 1 or 0 and in result a text A, B or C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select ProdID, 
       min(Qualified),
       case when min(Qualified) <> max(Qualified) 
            then 'YES'
            else 'NO'
       end as Has_different_results
from VarAnn_Data.dbo.tblOwnership
group by ProdID
```